# What PID is making outbound connections on port 25?

Tags: windows-server-2008, smtp

What is the most ready way to log the PID and process name of anything making an outbound connection on port 25? This is on a 2008 x32 server without the windows firewall enabled.

I'm decommissioning and old mail server and unfortunately a lot of the processes were defined by hand pointing to this host. I've got over 90% of the configuration updated but the remainder is a bit of a mystery.

I was thinking about using the following but it'll generate a lot of noise since this is a web server. I'm also not sure if it would work since the windows firewall is disabled.

```
auditpol /set /subcategory:"Filtering Platform Connection" /success:enable /failure:enable
```

Comment: netstat -b says `Displays the executable involved in creating each connection or
listening port. In some cases well-known executables host
multiple independent components, and in these cases the
sequence of components involved in creating the connection
or listening port is displayed. In this case the executable
name is in [] at the bottom, on top is the component it called,
and so forth until TCP/IP was reached. Note that this option
can be time-consuming and will fail unless you have sufficient
permissions.`

Comment: @NickW - That would require running it whist the email is being generated though wouldn't it? I've never used netstat used for prolonged data collection.

Comment: Have a look at the interval part of netstat, you could have it run every x seconds.. possibly pipe it through the windows equivalent of grep.. Also look at -o which will give you the process id, if you started piping itinto a log file filtering on port 25, it shouldn't get too huge one hopes..

Comment: Findstr seems to be the windows equiv :)

Comment: as an alternative you could install netmon 3.4 on it, but I'd do the netstat routine 1st.

Comment: @NickW, why not put that as the answer? Also, netmon, wireshark, etc.

Comment: @Ben, because in all honesty, I don't know if that was of any worth to him :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the following port logging tools:

- Port Reporter tool - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837243
- TCPView
- FPort v2.0 - TCP/IP Process to Port Mapper
- APorts - Active Ports